# How to calculate number of virtual pages

Tags: memory-management, cpu-architecture

virtual adress size: 32 bits

page size = 4K =2^12 bytes

what is the number of pages? 
i know the answer is (2^32)/(2^12) = 2^20 but why?

i think it should be (2^32)/(2^15) because of the byte bit conversion (2^12)*(8)=2^15

Comment: Does your machine have byte-addressable memory where every byte has its own address?  Or is it word-addressable (where every address is multiple consecutive bytes)?  NVM, we can tell it's byte-addressable from the right answer being 2^32 / 2^12.

Comment: If that is the correct answer we would have to assume that each address points to a 1 byte word?

Comment: No, each address is 1 byte, but it doesn't mean that a word is one byte.  A normal system like 32-bit x86 is like this, with 32-bit addresses and 4k pages, and byte-addressable memory.  32-bit x86's register width is 4 bytes.  (But it doesn't really have a single "word size", because there are wider vector registers...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every byte in memory has a numeric address starting from 0. The CPU has one or more *registers* which hold the address of that one byte which is being worked upon. A register is a physical device and has limits to how large a number it can store.

> virtual address size: 32 bits

This means the address register can store one address (number) which could be anything between `0` and `2^32 -1`.

As the largest address that the address register can store is `2^32 -1` there is no point in having more memory bytes. Because the CPU will never be able to work with them. So in general we assume the total memory to be `2^32` bytes.

> page size = 4K =2^12 bytes

The total memory of millions of bytes is actually organized in chunks called pages. Here total memory of `2^32` bytes is chunked into pages of `2^12` bytes.

> what is the number of pages?

the answer is (2^32)/(2^12) = 2^20. Good job!

> but why? i think it should be (2^32)/(2^15) because of the byte bit conversion (2^12)*(8)=2^15

Here `2^32` is the total number of bytes in memory. `2^12` is total number of bytes in a page. Both numerator and denominator should be in same units - bytes. So you need not convert the denominator to bits.

---

### Note:

I have used over simplification of terms like `memory`, `address`, `register` etc. Many of the statements made above are not valid for a real laptop - but useful for initial learning.

Comment: *there is no point in having more memory bytes. Because the CPU will never be able to work with them.*  You can have computers with more physical memory than they can map into one single virtual address space.  This is inconvenient for the OS kernel, but it's certainly possible to have multiple processes running, each having their 4GiB of virtual address space mapped to separate areas of physical memory.  32-bit x86 with PAE (physical address extensions) has 36-bit physical addresses but still 32-bit virtual addresses.

Comment: Exactly. Thats why the note: _Many of the statements made above are not valid for a real laptop - but useful for initial learning_

Comment: Statements that are false are not useful for learning at all.